# How do I propose a feature to the library working group?

Tags: c++, standards, standard-library

I would like to propose and discuss a feature that I think could be relevant for the C++ library, what is the most appropriate way or place to publish my proposal ?

I would like to stress the fact that I only care about the standard library for this, not the language itself.

Comment: http://isocpp.org/std/submit-a-proposal

Comment: I'm not sure this is in-topic.

Comment: @Jefffrey I'm pretty sure that the topic "C++ standards" fits the pattern of the logic behind this website and there are even tags for that ... why you think this could possibly be OT ?

Comment: @BenjaminLindley thanks, so no http://www.open-std.org/ ?

Comment: Once you get to the point of submitting an official, numbered proposal, it will be accessible through [WG21](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/), but the instructions for getting to that point are at the link I provided. C++ didn't really have an official website for a long time, except for the WG21 page. Now it does. http://isocpp.org/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The first port of call is certainly the [ISOCPP](http://isocpp.org/std/submit-a-proposal) page pointed to by Benjamin Lindley. The [official C++ committee page](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/) lists the upcoming dates, e.g., the submission dead-line (the next one is 2014-01-17) and the upcoming meetings (the next one is 2014-02-10 to 2014-02-15 in Issaquah). When you submit the proposal it needs to be in reasonably complete form as this version will be discussed, not an updated one created between the submission dead-line and the meeting.

The ISOCPP pages is fairly clear on the process. I want to emphasize a few points, though:

1. Somebody needs to push for the progress! Just submitting a paper won't get a proposal into the standard. That is, you'll need to pursue the inclusion and most likely make various adjustments to the details of the proposal.
2. You will need someone at the meetings who lobbies for the proposal: makes other people look at it, present it, defend it. Ideally you'd attend to lobby for the proposal but others have organized regular attendees to lobby for their proposal. Ideally you convince other ahead of the meeting to support the proposal, too.

Although you may target the library, where proposal gets handled in the end will be up to the committee. It will most likely go to the Library Evolution Working Group first and from there to an appropriate other group.